# Trouble with objected oriented programming, creating multiple instances

Tags: java, oop

I am new to OOP and Java Classes, so bear with me.

I am trying to create a class that allows me to store data about books, specifically the fields: Title, Author, Year published, Page count, Genre

Then with that class, I wish to have a main program that runs, asks for a number of books to enter and then allows the user to input the information for each book. Then, a summary is printed for each book.

I have attempted to program a class "bookClass" that allows input of the book information and then a class "bookTest" that creates an array using the bookClass.

This is the bookClass:

```
public class bookClass {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String year;
    private String pageCount;
    private String genre;
    private static int bookCount;

    public bookClass(String title, String author, String year, String pageCount, String genre) {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.setAuthor(author);
        this.setYear(year);
        this.setPageCount(pageCount);
        this.setGenre(genre);
        bookCount++;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public void setPageCount(String pageCount) {
        this.pageCount = pageCount;
    }
    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String getPageCount() {
        return pageCount;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public int getBookCount() {
        return bookCount
    }
}
```

This is the main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class bookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many books would you like to enter: ");
        int bookAmount = input.nextInt(); input.nextLine();
        String[][] books2DArray = new String[bookAmount][5];
        for (String[] books1DArray: books2DArray) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the title: ");
            String title = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the author ");
            String author = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the year: ");
            String year = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the page count: ");
            String pageCount = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the genre: ");
            String genre = input.nextLine();
            bookClass book = new bookClass(title, author, year, pageCount, genre);
            books1DArray[0] = book.getTitle();
            books1DArray[1] = book.getAuthor();
            books1DArray[2] = book.getYear();
            books1DArray[3] = book.getPageCount();
            books1DArray[4] = book.getGenre();

        }
        for (String[] books1DArray: books2DArray) {
            printSummary( books1DArray[0], books1DArray[1], books1DArray[2], books1DArray[3], books1DArray[4]);
        }
        System.out.println("There are" + book.getBookCount() + "books in the system");
    }

    public static void printSummary(String title, String author, String year, String pageCount, String genre) {
        System.out.format("%s written by %s was published in %s, has %s pages and is of the %s genre", title, author, year, pageCount, genre);

    }

}
```

I have multiple issues/questions:

Would it be better to create the array in the main class?

I feel like I am being highly inefficient as it feels like I am repeating myself in the code over and over. Some of the redundancy is necessary for good practice (such as getters and setters), but am I overdoing it?

In the for loop in the main class, I want to create multiple objects and add them to the array, but I am unsure how to do that as it would require different names to avoid being overwritten.

Also, calling getBookCount at the end of my main class does not work. Is there a reason for this?

I would appreciate any general advice or other things you may notice, as I feel as though I am fundamentally misunderstanding the use of Java classes.

Comment: Don't use a 2D array of Strings.  Use a 1D array of Books, or even a List of some kind.  And printSummary could be a non-static method of your Book class.

Answer (score 2):

You are learning Java, so you should learn Java [name conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html).

I assume your book class `public class BookClass`, you can write your test class that uses 1 array of `BookClass` (or `ArrayList` or any collection type you want), for example (Skip input checking)

```
public class BookTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many books would you like to enter: ");
        int bookAmount = input.nextInt(); input.nextLine();
        BookClass[] books = new BookClass[bookAmount];

        for (int i = 0; i < bookAmount; i++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the title: ");
            String title = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the author ");
            String author = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the year: ");
            String year = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the page count: ");
            String pageCount = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Please enter the genre: ");
            String genre = input.nextLine();
            books[i] = new BookClass(title, author, year, pageCount, genre);
        }
        for (BookClass book : books) {
            printSummary(book.getTitle(), book.getAuthor(), book.getYear(), book.getPageCount(), book.getGenre());
        }
        System.out.println("There are" + books.length + "books in the system");
    }

    public static void printSummary(String title, String author, String year, String pageCount, String genre) {
        System.out.format("%s written by %s was published in %s, has %s pages and is of the %s genre", title, author, year, pageCount, genre);
    }

}
```

You don't need static attribute in `BookClass` to store the number of books, you have many ways to do it.

Your `getBookCount` does not work because you call an undefined parameter `book` which you defined in side `for` loop. If you want, you should define a static getter method `public static int getBookCount()`, and access it `BookClass.getBookCount()`. But I advice you to do not use it to count object, because it can make wrong in complicated program when you remove object, use multi-threading with out synchronization ...